# Send keys to browser dialog windows in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I would like to print pages after each click in Chrome. So script should perform a click and after that send "CTRL+P" to open printing dialog and "ENTER" to save page as PDF file by default.

Comment: Did [this work](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/9776/send-keys-to-browser-dialog-windows)?

Comment: @MateMrše : Yes, that is a solution for the problem.

Comment: You could post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution on Katalon forum: https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/9776/send-keys-to-browser-dialog-windows
It is based on Java Robot class.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P)
// CTRL+P is now pressed 

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
// CTRL+P is now released
```